# Taylor Series vs. Series Function

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, series-expansion

Could someone please explain why the these two functions give two different results

```
Normal[Series[e^-Sqrt[x], {x, 0, 4}]]

Sum[Limit[D[e^-Sqrt[x], {x, n}], x -> 0], {n, 0, 4}]
```

These two function, as I understand, are supposed to give the same results, however when I run this code on Mathematica these two functions give two different result.

Comment: e is [E](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/E.html) I suspect? Built-in functions are capitalized. [See](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/GettingUsedToTheWolframLanguage.html).

Answer (score 6):

They should not be equal. Note that 
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{d^n}{dx^n} e^{-\sqrt{x}}=\infty
$$
for every integer $n$. What `Series` does is computing the fractional power series, a.k.a [Puiseux Series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puiseux_series), which cannot be obtained by evaluating the derivative.

You can see this problem with a simpler example: try expanding the function $f=\frac{1}{x}$ or $g=\sqrt{x}$ in a Taylor series around $x=0$ according to your definition.

Comment: see also [this question on math SE](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/429432/why-fractional-power-does-not-have-power-series-expansions)